# Julia Try Catch statement not catching all errors

Tags: function, try-catch, julia

I've written a function which contains a list of sub functions to evaluate. I have a try-catch statement around this block of sub functions so that if one of them throws an error the catch statement will ensure that the variables the subfunctions return will just be set to text messages.

Example Subfunction (working as expected)

```
function f(x)  
    SQRT = sqrt(x)
    return SQRT
end

f(9) #returns the square root of a positive number
> 3.0

f(-9) #error when you try to take the square root of a negative number
> LoadError: DomainError: while loading In[80], in expression 
  starting on line 1 in f at In[76]:2
```

Example Main Function with try-catch statement (not working as expected)

```
function g(y)
    a=[]
    b=[]
    try
        a=f(y)
        b="works"
    catch 
        a="no"
        b="no"
    end
    return a,b
end

g(9)
> (3.0,"works")

g(-9)
> LoadError: DomainError: while loading In[96], in expression 
  starting on line 1 in f at In[76]:2
```

I understand that the error is correct when I use f(x) since I haven't used a try-catch statement. However I'm expecting that the try-catch statement would catch this error when f(y) is evaluated inside of g(y) and would return a = "no" and b = "no". Why is the try-catch statement not picking this error up and working as expected?

Is there a way to get this statement to work? I need it to work this way to avoid putting try-catch statements into all of the many subfunctions I have written. In this example it would be easy to just insert the try-catch into f(x) and the problem would be solved as per below, but I don't want to do this in my real code because the subfunctions could fail in a number of places and I'd have to significantly alter my code to take account of all of the potential failures.

Example Subfunction with try-catch statement (working as expected)

```
function h(x)  
    SQRT = []
    try
        SQRT = sqrt(x)
    catch 
        SQRT = "no"
    end
    return SQRT
end
h(9)
> 3.0

h(-9)
> "no"
```

Example Main Function (working as expected)

```
function i(y)
    a=h(y)
    b="works"
    return a,b
end

i(9)
> (3.0,"works")

i(-9)
> ("no","works")
```

In other words, I don't want to have to use the method in my second example, is there a way to get what I want using something similar to my first example?

I'm using Julia version 0.4.6

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried reproducing in a clean REPL session?

Comment: I've tried this on Julia 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5-dev and it works in all of them. Please do try in a clean session and see if you can reproduce. Otherwise, please give details of what version of Julia you're using.

Comment: I had included my version at the end of the question. I tried what you suggested and restarted the repl and it is working. Should I delete this question since it works as it should?

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer to your question?  Then it can be marked as answered and easily seen by others as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks StefanKarpinski for suggesting a restart of the repl session, that worked.

> "I've tried this on Julia 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5-dev and it works in all of them. Please do try in a clean session and see if you can reproduce. Otherwise, please give details of what version of Julia you're using.

– StefanKarpinski Jul 6 at 4:55"